# Is there a substitute for port wine in a dessert risotto?

Tags: substitutions, alcohol, wine

I am looking for a substitute for port wine in a "dessert risotto" that I would like to make. It's not that I'm worried about the alcohol (I would actually prefer to use the port), I just can't purchase alcohol since I'm under 21 and living in the US.

Since context is everything, here is the recipe for the [Port Raspberries & Cream Risotto](http://www.risottorecipe.org/port-raspberries-cream-risotto.html) I plan to cook. .

Again, I am unable to purchase alcohol (except for cooking wines), so please do not suggest alcoholic alternatives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please do not use a cooking wine. Those are awful. Pick a juice, any juice. I'd say cranberry. You probably don't want anything too sweet.

Comment: In equal proportions, I presume?

Comment: Yep. It should work fine.

Answer (score 10):

The best nonalcoholic substitution that I can think of for a ruby-style port would be pomegranate or black cherry juice, something not from concentrate.  The POM brand is readily available, at least in my local market.

You may want to thicken this a little to help mimic the silky texture of a port.  I'd recommend starting with about 12 liquid oz, bringing it up to a bare simmer in an open saucepan, and reducing down to the required 8 ounces.  If you want to get even closer in flavor... maybe grate in a little nutmeg and dark chocolate, either in the reducing juice or into the final risotto.

Tawny port (though I doubt this is what the recipe is looking for) would be tougher, but might be replicable with a little experimentation.